# Is there any caffeine in kuding tea?

Tags: tea, caffeine

Does anyone know if the bitter kuding tea (苦丁茶) contain caffeine?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe it depends on the source of the leaves. Kuding can be made from both a wax tree species and a holly species. I do not know about the wax tree, but teas made from holly do contain caffeine (Yerba mate, for example).

Comment: Ah good to know about the Yerba mate, but I still want to know the caffeine content in the chinese Kuding tea.

Comment: Unfortunately, I have not been able to find the amount of caffeine in this tea. I think this is partially because, like I said, it can be made from different sources (some with caffeine and some without).